# Visual Studio Code Pylance не видит внутри массива, как настроить?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylance

кто знает, как настроить Pylance видеть внутри массива?

```
class cl:
    a = 1


mass = []

mass.append(cl())
```

`mass[0]` < - "не отображает список данных массива"

а `Jedi` видит.

Answer (score 1):

Видимо Pylance не пытается обобщить тип всех элементов списка по одному добавленному элементу. Можно добавить аннотацию типа к списку, тогда будет подсказывать:

```
from typing import List


class cl:
    asdf = 1


mass: List[cl] = []

mass.append(cl())
```

[image: Скриншот]

Answer (score 0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Работает и так, но хотелось бы, как Jedi.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! похоже, это не ответ, а дополнение к вопросу. если так и есть, то дополните, пожалуйста, текст вопроса, нажав ссылку «править» ниже текста вопроса, а данный «ответ», пожалуйста, удалите

Comment: Если хотелось бы как Jedi, почему не хотите использовать Jedi?

Comment: Потому что jedi видит это, но не видит ещё больше других данных в объектах. А ещё Jedi отключает Pylint. А он мне нравиться.

Comment: Тогда используйте аннотации типов, как я в своем ответе написал. Это в любом случае полезно.